# Set a Cell Value Based on Multiple Columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below script to set the cell value to "Y", when two columns from one sheet match two columns from another sheet, inside same spreadsheet. The 4 columns are not in the same position in their respective sheets. When I run the script it only puts one "Y" in a cell of the Cancel Reg column.

```
function cancelRegistration() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetR = ss.getSheetByName("Registration");
    var sheetCR = ss.getSheetByName("Cancel Registration");
    var dataR = sheetR.getDataRange().getValues();
    var dataCR = sheetCR.getDataRange().getValues();
    var headerRow = 1;
    var headers = dataR[0];
    var cellR = sheetR.getActiveCell();
    var cellCR = sheetCR.getActiveCell();
    var rowR = cellR.getRowIndex();
    var rowCR = cellCR.getRowIndex();
    for (var i = 1; i < dataR.length && i < dataCR.length; ++i) {
        var eventIdR = rowR[1];
        var emailR = rowR[7];
        var eventIdCR = rowCR[1];
        var emailCR = rowCR[4];
        var urlCol = headers.indexOf("Cancel Reg");
            if (eventIdR !== '' && emailR !== '') {
                if (rowR[1] === rowCR[1] && rowR[7] === rowCR[4]) {
                    sheetR.getRange(headerRow + i, 10).setValue("Y");
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by changing ss to sheetR in. var data =ss.getDataRange().getValues();

Comment: Thank you. I tried it. I still only get one "Y".

Comment: Next. for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {

Comment: Still one "Y". It's like it just looks once and doesn't find all of the matches. At the moment there should be three "Y" occurrences.

Comment: indexOf("Cancel Reg", "ID", "Email:", "Email");   you cannot use multiple arguments in this way

Comment: Okay thank you. I removed all but the first. Never was sure if you could have multiple in there. Still only 1 "Y".

Comment: If you followed the 3 suggestions by @ScampMichael carefully, the function should now work. If it doesn't, I think there are logic errors (actual referenced values might be different than you think). Pay attention that elements in arrays starts indexing from 0, while cells in ranges  - from 1.

Comment: @ZygD yeah I've checked multiple times to make sure the correct number is used for the column. They are the correct numbers being used, unless the following isn't correct: if it's in the [] the columns start at 0, and if they are in () they start at 1. For example, row[1] is equal to the second column and sheetCR.getRange(headerRow + i, 2).getValue(); the 2 is equal to the same column as the 1 in row[1]. I hope that made sense.

Comment: @ScampMichael I looked at the actual row positions of both sheets that are being compared for the "same data" email and event ID. The only time a Y pops up is when the data is the same for the same row position on each sheet. In this case, it's only row 1. I'm not sure how to change the script so that it can match say row 3 on Registration sheet with row 2 on cancel registration sheet.

Comment: @ScampMichael got it two give the right amount of "Y", however they are in the row position of the Cancel Registration sheet (there are two entries there). There are 3 entries for the Registration. So the two "Y"s are in row 1 and row 2. Need to figure out how to get them to be in their correct positions on the Registration sheet.